# Dev site throws "this.hoverable is undefined" while Live site does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have two "identical" Wordpress sites, one local/dev site, and one live. The live site works just fine, while the identical local/dev site has (*only recently and without ANY changes to the code*) started throwing a fatal JS/jQuery error whenever a jQuery dialog is initialized on the back-end (wp-admin).  I can’t begin to guess why and can't overstate how nearly identical the dev site is to the live site (*confirmed using Beyond Compare difference engine*).

Having developed an e-commerce/bookkeeping plugin for Wordpress on my local WAMP server (Windows XP),  I installed it on brand new Wordpress site (shared hosting account with Blue Host).

For several weeks, things had progressed quite nicely on the new site, when I decided to dive back into the code to make a few small improvements to the work-flow.  Returning to my development server and site(s) I was shocked to find that ANY call to a jQuery UI Dialog, 
the dev site throws

> Error: TypeError: this.hoverable is undefined
>   Source File: http: //
>   localhost/demox/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-position,wp-pointer&ver=3.6
>   Line: 17

I can't single-out any bit of code to offer up for review, especially as it all works as expected on the live site.  Is it possible this is the result of some or other recent Windows update causing a behavioral issue with my WAMP Server?

**FWIW** here's my dev config.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'demox');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'l[>877xK}[.a_qkRW1&BAHAng+J[f?G|[zBDAz6Q(*_L.9KH 0@Z(Ci7^Rf=U$M}');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'P=8if~;H.J0,}Oc0p~cgBxn=Hs$%CABheXI~,=uk$d!LguIJx72uh0Kp$mSL9`3b');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'qm-i;B]wc{i?vdSF^w;{*?5yIwkCTRY[Vza[<G=/]@,i,a-n??hAowouy?PIRp@(');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '{[sr&)_-H@3-t`H]v7$/}@;:PP0tte9f>o@NMBw0;B&`_w.$xrPPem]xW)!$$6>2');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '0rMsc8D8x.puf(K!.:Y%uj&j?F*.zL<01-!yikp8kIuh 6_%A>UEoZ6d|, p%N.8');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', ' IKV7Bx(/,u#onKpV%,6-x=UT szLJ<S#c+P0*!|1dDyloycnTPz?Q2!CNSUQ:qa');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '*T5TYMe/{kQ;j~Q#g-<r)VBlPHP%48K4:ty^=yLa76kancvTiGNZch&52]cY(~!<');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '+,J0[,;uO!{w?0z7#efVvI!7{vjE7}.1T*0EgW9=K0]Nb)!j{[@0{*pHSlDu`Sub');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: So, I think your dev site doesn't concatenate scripts, whereas your production site does. What you should do is add `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` right before the last line in wp-config.php on your dev site and retry. Worpress script concatenation apparently can mess up things sometimes (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-is-no-longer-working).

Comment: @DDS
Thanks, tried that, but to no avail
I've just confirmed however, that deactivating Yoast Wordpress SEO, and the issue goes away.  Still, both dev and production sites are running virtually identical copies of Yoast SEO. 
Gheesh. What a conundrum...